# What does the D flag in the code segment descriptor do for x86-64 instructions?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, intel, memory-segmentation

I'm trying to understand the workings of the `D flag` in the code segment descriptor when used in the x86-64 code. It's set in the `D/B` bit 22 of the code segment descriptor as shown on this diagram:

[image]

The Intel documentation (from section [3.4.5 Segment Descriptors](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf)) states the following:

[image]

> D/B (default operation size/default stack pointer size and/or upper
>   bound) flag
>
> Performs different functions depending on whether the segment
>   descriptor is an executable code segment, an expand-down data segment,
>   or a stack segment. (This flag should always be set to 1 for 32-bit
>   code and data segments and to 0 for 16-bit code and data segments.)
>
> • Executable code segment.  The flag is called the D flag and it
>   indicates the default length for  effective addresses and operands
>   referenced by instructions in the segment.  If the flag is set, 32-bit
>   addresses and 32-bit or 8-bit operands are  assumed; if it is clear,
>   16-bit addresses and 16-bit or 8-bit operands are assumed.  The
>   instruction prefix 66H can be used to select an operand size other
>   than the default, and the prefix 67H can be used select an address
>   size other than the default.

So I'm trying to understand which x86-64 instructions does it affect and how?

PS. When I try to run some tests (in Windows kernel) by setting that bit on, the OS immediately triple faults.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `L` (long mode) is set for a code segment descriptor, `D` must be clear.  The L=1 / D=1 combination is currently meaningless / reserved.  Intel documents this nearby in the same document you were looking at.

If `L` is clear, then `D` selects between 16 and 32-bit mode.  (i.e. the default operand / address size).  And yes, 16-bit protected mode exists, but no, nobody uses it.

---

There are only 3 possibilities for default address/operand-size:

- 16-bit modes (real, vm86, protected):  default address and operand-size = 16-bit
- 32-bit protected mode: default address and operand-size = 32-bit
- 64-bit mode: default address size = 64-bit, default operand-size = 32-bit

There's no option to have 16x 64-bit registers but a default operand size of 16-bit or 64-bit.  Or a default address size of 32-bit overrideable to 64.

Comment: Oh, so what I was doing by having the L bit set and by also setting the D bit was "illegal" and that is why I was getting a triple fault, correct?

Comment: Hold on though. After reading the Intel documentation once again (the one that I showed above) -- why are they mentioning the `66H` and `67H` prefixes in the same paragraph where they discuss the `D` flag for the executable code? Those prefixes work only in the 64-bit long mode when the `L` flag is set in the code segment descriptor. So if the `D` flag has to be cleared in that case, why do they bring up those prefixes? That's the part that confuses me.

Comment: @MikeF: No, it's REX prefixes that are long-mode only.  Operand-size prefixes swap between 16 and 32-bit in 32-bit mode the same as in 64-bit mode, or the opposite way in 16-bit mode.  (e.g. `add eax,eax` needs a 66H prefix in 16-bit mode, but not in 32 or 64.)  Look at some assembler output for `add eax, [esi]` vs. `add ax, [si]` in 16 vs. 32 bit mode.  (e.g. run `nasm -l` to make a listing that includes machine code)