# Which value will be returned by calling func

Tags: pointers, assembly, x86, stack, nasm

I have some misunderstanding about esp pointer.

below are the code which shown in one of previous exams.
The returned value is 1.

```
func:   xor eax,eax
        call L3
        L1: call dword[esp]
        inc eax
        L2: ret
        L3: call dword[esp]
        L4: ret
```

Now, I will explain how I think and hope someone will correct me or approve.
This is how I think when I know what is the answer so I am not sure I`m thinking correctly at all.

1. eax = 0
2. We push to stack return address which is the next line, i.e label L1.
3. We jump to L3.
4. We push to stack return address which is the next line, i.e label L4.
5. We jump to L1.
6. We push to stack return address which is the next line, i.e inc eax.
7. We jump to L4.
8. We jump to line where is inc eax and stack is now empty.
9. eax = 1.
10. we end here(at label L2) and return 1.

Comment: why question is down-voted? please let me know, I will improve it.

Comment: I think `eax` = 2 and the caller of func is called once from the instruction at L1.

Comment: You need to keep going after step 10.  Where does 10. return to?

Comment: I think I miss something, step 10 is the end. It means - return via eax register to function who call this func.

Comment: `retn` means "pop the dword off the stack's top into `eip`". It does not unconditionally "return to function which called this function", it returns to whatever address is on top of the stack. Also, your step 8 "stack is now empty" comment is wrong.

Comment: This isn't a valid function; it can't be said to "return" because it eventually *calls* its return address, jumping there with 2 extra dwords on the stack (including the original return address) vs. if it had returned.

Comment: The key thing you’re missing is that `call [esp]` doesn’t remove the address from the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `eax` = 2 and the caller of `func` is called once from the instruction at `L1`. In the following I will trace execution to show you what I mean.

I re-arranged your example a bit to make it more readable. This is NASM source. I think this should be equivalent to the original (assuming [the D bit and B bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133724/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-386s-d-bit) are set, i.e. you're running in normal 32-bit mode).

```
        bits 32
func:
        xor eax, eax
        call L3
.returned:
L1:
        call near [esp]
.returned:
        inc eax
L2:
        retn
L3:
        call near [esp]
.returned:
L4:
        retn
```

Now assume we start with some function that does this:

```
foo:
        call func
.returned:
        X
        retn
```

This is what happens:

1. At `foo` we call `func`. The address of `foo.returned` is put on the stack (say, stack slot -1).
2. At `func` we set `eax` to zero.
3. Next we call `L3`. The address of `func.returned` = `L1` is put on the stack (slot -2).
4. At `L3` we call the dword on top of the stack. Here this is `func.returned`. The address of `L3.returned` = `L4` is put on the stack (slot -3).
5. At `L1` we call the dword on top of the stack. Here this is `L3.returned`. The address of `L1.returned` is put on the stack (slot -4).
6. At `L4` we return. This pops `L1.returned` (from slot -4) into `eip`.
7. At `L1.returned` we do `inc eax`, setting `eax` to 1.
8. Then at `L2` we return. This pops `L3.returned` (from slot -3) into `eip`.
9. At `L4` we return. This pops `func.returned` (from slot -2) into `eip`.
10. At `L1` we call the dword on top of the stack. Here this is `foo.returned`. The address of `L1.returned` is put on the stack (slot -2).
11. At `foo.returned` we execute whatever is there which I marked `X`. Assuming that the function returns using a `retn` eventually then...
12. ... we return. This pops `L1.returned` (from slot -2) into `eip`.
13. At `L1.returned` we do `inc eax`. Assuming that `X` did not alter `eax` then we now have `eax` = 2.
14. Then at `L2` we return. This pops `foo.returned` (from slot -1) into `eip`.

If my assumptions are correct then `eax` is 2 in the end.

---

Note that it is really strange to call the return address on top of the stack. I cannot imagine a practical use for this.

Also note that if, in a debugger, you proceed-step the call to `func` in `foo` then at step 11 the debugger might return control to the user, with `eax` equal to 1. However, the stack is not balanced at this point.

Comment: You're right, if you throw this into `_start` as a static executable to single-step it, at step `10` the `call [esp]` uses the incoming top-of-stack as a call target.  In this case it's `argc` (1), so it faults there, with EAX=1.  So this code isn't a ABI-compliant function, and there's no real way to say what it does!  If called from a caller that does `leave` or similar after the call, the extra return address will be discarded, otherwise it breaks the stack (e.g. `pop ebx`).  It looked interesting, but turns out it's a pretty poor exam question.