# In x86 32 bit protected mode, can we still use SP rather than ESP register when use PUSH/POP instructions?

Tags: assembly, x86, stack-memory, protected-mode, stack-pointer

I don't know when use SP register and when use ESP register, besides, I want to know when use ESP register, does it always decrease 4 and can't decrease 2?

Comment: Are you asking whether you *should* normally (no), or whether it's possible to get the hardware to do that at all? (yes)

Answer (score 6):

Technically SP can be used in `push` and `pop` in 32bit mode, but it requires modifying a flag that you usually cannot change.

Whether SP or ESP is used in pmode is governed by the B flag in the segment descriptor referred to by `SS`. Normally in user-mode code, that's not something you have access to, so you cannot change it.

There are similar but independent mechanisms for the default operand size, and default address size (*not* the same thing as the stack address size, the plain address size is used for the memory operand of `push [mem]` and `pop [mem]`). These are 3 separate things, see below.

> when use ESP register, does it always decrease 4 and can't decrease 2

Pushing/popping a `word` is possible and even easy, it still is even in 64bit mode. All you need for this is the operand size override prefix, 66h. For example `push dx` is absolutely encodable in both 32bit and even 64bit mode (though I do not recommend using it). This is independent of whether SP or ESP is used.

So there are three separate sizes at play, and two of them have an override prefix available to change it:

1. The operand size, pushing a `word` or `dword`, this determines whether the stack pointer is moved by 2 or by 4. Normally in 32bit mode the default size would be set to 32bit, but the operand size override prefix can be used to encode `push dx` in 32bit mode (and even in 64bit mode).
2. The address size, which is for `push` and `pop` with an explicit memory operand, not for the implicit stack location. The address size override prefix can be used to encode for example `push dword [bx]` and both prefixes can be used together to encode `push word [bx]`. In 64bit mode, the address size override prefix causes the address to be interpreted as a 32bit address, not a 16bit address, so `push qword [bx]` is impossible.
3. The stack address size, which is only determined by the B flag in the stack segment descriptor, there is no override prefix for it.

Comment: The "B" [stands for "Big"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63133724/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-386s-d-bit)